# Can we manage a Github pull request from Azure Devops pipelines?

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions, github-api

Is it possible to involve an azure CI pipeline to handle a github pull request?

I have a requirement where once the pull request is created on a particular branch, it has to invoke a ci pipeline to run the test cases and if it is successful, merge the request else close.

I tried many options, where connecting to git repo using API and cloning and checking in.
But the pull request is mandatory for the business.

Is there any ways to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the pr trigger in azure pipelines. You can set your `pr` trigger for the pipeline to run the tests and after this pipeline completes successfully you can trigger another one with `resources`. In this pipeline you can merge the pr or cancel it using a rest api.

```
# azure-pipelines-trigger.yml
name: SecondPipeline 
trigger: none
    # this pipeline will be triggered by another pipeline
    resources:
      pipelines:
      - pipeline: previous-pipeline-trigger   # Name of the pipeline resource
        source: First-Pipeline-yaml # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
        project: Trigger-Pipeline-From-Another-Pipeline # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
        trigger: true # enable the trigger
```

https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Trigger-Pipeline-From-Another-Pipeline

[image]

Finally in the pipeline which will be called after the tests finish you will have to add a powershell task or a cmd task to merge the pull request.

Github merge pull request API:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#merge-a-pull-request